# How to disable writing in cookie?

Tags: cookies

I'm trying to disable writing data in a specific cookie on a website,
At the same time, i want the data to be sent,
So it means, i send cookie data and don't want to receive any,
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookie is just a mechanism to store information at per client basis or in client layer above the session layer. In general people hate cookies cause they can do creepy stuff and some website is using resources on their PC.

When you say I want to store a cookie that I never want to read, its really shady. **No browser should allow this sort of cookie.** You might want to re-look at your architecture.

But may be I donno what exactly you mean.

Comment: I mean, i just want the cookie to send data that is currently written on it, the website will try to update the cookie with new data and i want to stop this step, i just want it to send the data that is written on the cookie not the data that is going to be updated .

Comment: The only way I can think of is read the cookie from request and update it into the outgoing cookie.